# Expected value of Bernoulli variable from the moment generating function

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, moment-generating-function

I am studying the Moment Generating Functions of discrete random variables and I got an exercise asking to derive the mgf of a Bernoulli variable and its expected value.

I start from the definition of mgf:
$$
M_{X}(t) = E[e^{tX}] = [e^{t\cdot 0} \cdot q + e^{t\cdot 1} \cdot p] = q + e^{t}p \stackrel{\text{t=0}}{=} q + p
$$

But, as everybody knows from the theory, the expected value of a Bernoulli is not $q + p$, but $p$.

So, I don't know how to solve this dilemma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating the expected value of the moment-generating function, not the expected value of $x$.

To derive the expected value of $x$ from the MGF, we need to find the derivative with respect to $t$ and evaluate it at $t = 0$:

$${\mathrm{d} \over \mathrm{dx}}(q + pe^t)|_{t=0} = pe^t|_{t=0} = p$$